# How do I write constraints that is only active at Construction Heuristics phase?

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I would like to have some constraints that is only active during construction heuristics phase, so I write like this:

```
fun aConstraintOnlyActiveInCHPhase(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint {
        return constraintFactory.from(MyPlanningEntity::class.java)
            .ifExists(MyPlanningEntity::class.java,
                Joiners.filtering({entity1,entity2 -> entity2.myplanningvariable == null})
            )
            ...
            ...
            .penalize("aConstraintOnlyActiveInCHPhase",HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
    }
```

However this works for all but the last planning entity, when the last planning entity is initialized, there is no other uninitialized planning entity so this constraint will not be active.

How do I write constraints that is active for all planning entity during construction heuristics phase?

Furthermore, how do I write constraints that is active in different phase during solving?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you do not. The score represents the measure of quality of your solution, as it pertains to a particular problem. The problem you are solving is the same in every solver phase.

If you change your constraints, you are changing the optimization problem, and therefore might as well run a new solver with a new configuration. Whatever solution you got until that point may as well be thrown out of the window, because it was optimized for different criteria which are no longer valid.

That said, the constraint above will do what you want if you start using `forEachIncludingNullVars(...)` instead. This will include uninitialized entities, helping you avoid the `ifExists(...)` hack.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. The reason I want to do this in CH phase is to generate an initial solution that I know will lead to better solution later based on the moves I setup, even though I know the initial solution is not good and actually far from a final solution.  Letting the CH phase to come up with its own initialization based on the constraints will be much more harder for my moves to tweak the initialized solution from CH phase.  I could use custom initialization but I though I could leverage some CH phase constraints and let optaplanner initialize it.